# How can I create a fluent nh classmap for a class that has a table-per-class entity as a child?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to figure out how to replace automapping that works with class maps in fluent nhibernate. Here's my current scenario:

I have entity "Foo" that entities "FooSubclassA" and "FooSubclassB" are subclasses of. There's no discriminator column, as they are using the same id's, and a SubclassMap. That works fine; I can retrieve lists of FooSubclassA's and FooSubclassB's, and see the properties that get inherited with "Foo".

My problem is now I have a class "Bar", that has a one-to-one property of "Foo". I want that Foo instance to either be a FooSubclassA or FooSubclassB depending on where it actually finds the Foo_id. My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to define this via classmaps.

I do have a field in the "Bar" entity that could be used as a discriminator, if I need to do that. (Bar.IsFooSubclassA)

Answer (score 1):

Do you call `KeyColumn("some_column_name");` in your SubclassMappings? This is needed to get a table-per-subclass mapping. Then the reference from "Bar" to "Foo" is just a simple `References()` call for many-to-one or `HasOne()` for one-to-one.

The following may not apply to your question but I'll write it for completeness:

If your mapping is correct you maybe get a correct entity back but just don't see it. You should know that a polymorphic many-to-one or one-to-one that is lazy loaded will always be a proxy of the base class ("Foo") because NHibernate can't know what subclass will be there when the proxy is created. For this reason you can't just check the type with the "is" operator (or similar).

If you don't use lazy loading or eagerly fetch the association when you load "Bar" you should get a "normal" "FooSubclassA" or "FooSubclassB" object back.

If you need lazy loading you can get a workaround here: http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks very much for this; the lazy-loading does seem a bit hacky (as the title suggests, naturally). My keycolumn was in fact correct, but your explanation on why I can't do what I want makes sense -- I had hoped to use is/as to get a strongly-typed object. My biggest question is how on earth the automapper is able to do it when I can't find a way to do the same via ClassMap/SubclassMap.